# Qt Quick cross compiled application didn't show images on raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, image, qt

I cross compiled Qt5.14.2 for my raspberry pi 4 on a raspberry pi OS lite

after that I created a Qt Quick application on my Ubuntu and I integrated images in my qml file

```
Image {
        id: compteur
        x: 223
        y: 102
        width: 570
        height: 227
        source: "images/b2.png"
    }
```

so the image `b2.png` on my ubuntu is under `~/Desktop/test_v1/images`
and the executable `test_v1` was generated under `~/Desktop/build-test_v1-Qt5pi-Release`

on my raspberry pi I copied this executable and copied also all the directory `test_v1`

but when executing the application it worked well but the images didn't show up

I tried also to put the images and the executable in the same directory but couldn't work also.

if you know what should I change please tell me !

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and it may help someone so I am going to post it.

I used Qt resources https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html and it will help you to integrate the images to the executable.

so under my test_v1 directory I created a file `image.qrc` (I used nano to create it)
after that in qtcreator I added to my project this file (`right click on the project -> add existing files-> choose image.qrc`)

`image.qrc` containes :

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC> <RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>images/b2.png</file>
</qresource>
 </RCC>
```

the image b2.png is under test_v1/images